# Turning a running total to a daily count

Tags: gnuplot

This feels like a basic high school math thing I've clearly forgotten. Anyhoo, I have data that looks like:

```
$Data << EOD
2020-08-09 4
2020-08-10 5
2020-08-11 6
2020-08-13 7
2020-08-14 8
EOD
set xdata time
set timefmt "%Y-%m-%d"
plot $Data u 1:2
```

Which looks like [image: gnuplot time series plot]

Sidenote: Not sure why first value is not plotted... do you?

I just want to see the daily increments, like so:

```
$Data << EOD
2020-08-09 1
2020-08-10 1
2020-08-11 1
2020-08-13 1
2020-08-14 1
EOD
set xdata time
set timefmt "%Y-%m-%d"
plot $Data u 1:2
```

How do I get Gnuplot to just show the daily increments as I want, without editing the Data as I have done above? Any tips to link the points for readability would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your first point is plotted, your y axis does not start at zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** revised version after piecewise getting more information.

Plotting is like looping the data columns. In the code below `x0` and `y0` hold the previous values and `x1` and `y1` the current values. The daily change is `(y1-y0)` divided by `(x1-x0)` multiplied by 3600*24. Remember, in gnuplot date and time are handled internally in seconds passed from January, 1st 1970 00:00:00. Check `help time/date`. Also check `help operations binary` and serial evaluation.

**Data:** (`Singapore.csv`)

```
Singapore,2020-08-22 04:27:49,1.2833,103.8333,56216,27,53651,2538,Singapore,960.9009249543145,0.048029030880888
Singapore,2020-08-21 04:27:41,1.2833,103.8333,56099,27,53119,2953,Singapore,958.9010422123966,0.04812920016399579
Singapore,2020-08-20 04:27:43,1.2833,103.8333,56031,27,52810,3194,Singapore,957.7387172,0.04818761042994057
Singapore,2020-08-18 04:27:56,1.2833,103.8333,55838,27,52350,3461,Singapore,954.4397653265801,0.048354167412872955
Singapore,2020-08-17 04:27:20,1.2833,103.8333,55747,27,51953,3767,Singapore,952.884300971755,0.048433099538988646
Singapore,2020-08-16 04:27:42,1.2833,103.8333,55661,27,51521,4113,Singapore,951.414301691371,0.04850793194516807
Singapore,2020-08-15 04:27:31,1.2833,103.8333,55580,27,51049,4504,Singapore,950.0297674854277,0.04857862540482188
Singapore,2020-08-14 04:51:19,1.2833,103.8333,55497,27,50736,4734,Singapore,948.6110472497082,0.04865127844748365
Singapore,2020-08-13 04:29:15,1.2833,103.8333,55395,27,50520,4848,Singapore,946.8675597311133,0.048740861088545896
Singapore,2020-08-12 04:27:29,1.2833,103.8333,55353,27,50128,5198,Singapore,946.1496531058093,0.048777844019294345
Singapore,2020-08-11 04:35:08,1.2833,103.8333,55292,27,49609,5656,Singapore,945.10697919763,0.04883165738262316
Singapore,2020-08-10 04:34:55,1.2833,103.8333,55104,27,48915,6162,Singapore,941.8934923986508,0.048998257839721254
Singapore,2020-08-09 04:34:54,1.2833,103.8333,54929,27,48583,6319,Singapore,938.9022147932179,0.04915436290484079
Singapore,2020-08-08 04:34:53,1.2833,103.8333,54797,27,48312,6458,Singapore,936.6459368279776,0.04927277040713908
Singapore,2020-08-07 04:35:11,1.2833,103.8333,54555,27,48031,6497,Singapore,932.5094272250363,0.04949133901567226
Singapore,2020-08-06 04:35:02,1.2833,103.8333,54254,27,47768,6459,Singapore,927.364429743692,0.049765915877170344
Singapore,2020-08-05 04:34:43,1.2833,103.8333,53346,27,47454,5865,Singapore,911.8439722252184,0.05061297941738837
Singapore,2020-08-04 04:41:59,1.2833,103.8333,53051,27,47179,5845,Singapore,906.8015328332033,0.050894422348306344
Singapore,2020-08-03 04:34:35,1.2833,103.8333,52825,27,46926,5872,Singapore,902.9385114684727,0.05111216280170374
Singapore,2020-08-02 04:34:47,1.2833,103.8333,52512,27,46740,5745,Singapore,897.5883978084703,0.05141681901279708
Singapore,2020-08-01 04:36:27,1.2833,103.8333,52205,27,46491,5687,Singapore,892.3408422377969,0.051719183986208214
Singapore,2020-07-31 04:35:18,1.2833,103.8333,51809,27,46308,5474,Singapore,885.572008342075,0.05211449748113262
Singapore,2020-07-30 04:35:05,1.2833,103.8333,51531,27,46098,5406,Singapore,880.8201502031592,0.052395645339698434
Singapore,2020-07-29 04:35:11,1.2833,103.8333,51197,27,45893,5277,Singapore,875.1110832305046,0.05273746508584488
Singapore,2020-07-28 04:58:43,1.2833,103.8333,50838,27,45692,5119,Singapore,868.9746908856455,0.05310987843738935
Singapore,2020-07-27 04:35:02,1.2833,103.8333,50369,27,45521,4821,Singapore,860.958066903086,0.05360439953145784
Singapore,2020-07-26 04:35:00,1.2833,103.8333,49888,27,45352,4509,Singapore,852.736326741868,0.05412123155869147
Singapore,2020-07-25 04:47:39,1.2833,103.8333,49375,27,45172,4176,Singapore,843.967610104228,0.05468354430379747
Singapore,2020-07-24 05:30:40,1.2833,103.8333,49098,27,45015,4056,Singapore,839.2328449802002,0.05499205670292069
Singapore,2020-07-23 05:15:04,1.2833,103.8333,48744,27,44795,3922,Singapore,833.1819177097823,0.055391432791728215
Singapore,2020-07-22 04:34:42,1.2833,103.8333,48434,27,44584,3823,Singapore,827.8830830944443,0.055745963579303795
Singapore,2020-07-21 04:38:46,1.2833,103.8333,48035,27,44371,3637,Singapore,821.0629701540578,0.0562090142604351
Singapore,2020-07-20 05:34:40,1.2833,103.8333,47912,27,44086,3799,Singapore,818.9605293228108,0.056353314409751214
Singapore,2020-07-19 04:34:58,1.2833,103.8333,47655,27,43833,3795,Singapore,814.5676244965466,0.056657223796033995
Singapore,2020-07-18 04:34:45,1.2833,103.8333,47453,27,43577,3849,Singapore,811.1148354891327,0.05689840473731903
Singapore,2020-07-17 04:34:50,1.2833,103.8333,47126,27,43256,3843,Singapore,805.5254196206959,0.057293213937104785
Singapore,2020-07-16 04:44:59,1.2833,103.8333,46878,27,42988,3863,Singapore,801.2863519284253,0.0575963138359145
Singapore,2020-07-15 04:34:39,1.2833,103.8333,46630,27,42737,3866,Singapore,797.0472842361551,0.05790263778683251
Singapore,2020-07-14 04:34:46,1.2833,103.8333,46283,26,42541,3716,Singapore,791.1160080699542,0.05617613378562323
Singapore,2020-07-13 04:43:04,1.2833,103.8333,45961,26,42285,3650,Singapore,785.6120572759579,0.05656970039816366
Singapore,2020-07-12 04:34:30,1.2833,103.8333,45783,26,42026,3731,Singapore,782.5695006258608,0.056789638075268115
Singapore,2020-07-11 04:34:26,1.2833,103.8333,45614,26,41780,3808,Singapore,779.6807811097573,0.05700004384618757
Singapore,2020-07-10 04:34:24,1.2833,103.8333,45423,26,41645,3752,Singapore,776.4160152661134,0.057239724368711886
Singapore,2020-07-09 04:34:23,1.2833,103.8333,45298,26,41323,3949,Singapore,774.2793884050902,0.05739767760166012
Singapore,2020-07-08 05:33:48,1.2833,103.8333,45140,26,41002,4112,Singapore,771.5786920527565,0.057598582188746125
Singapore,2020-07-07 04:34:00,1.2833,103.8333,44983,26,40717,4240,Singapore,768.8950887153113,0.05779961318720406
Singapore,2020-07-06 04:33:57,1.2833,103.8333,44800,26,40441,4333,Singapore,765.7670669907733,0.05803571428571429
Singapore,2020-07-05 04:33:46,1.2833,103.8333,44664,26,40117,4521,Singapore,763.4424169659796,0.05821243059287121
Singapore,2020-07-04 04:33:51,1.2833,103.8333,44479,26,39769,4684,Singapore,760.280209211665,0.058454551586141774
Singapore,2020-07-03 04:33:54,1.2833,103.8333,44310,26,39429,4855,Singapore,757.3914896955614,0.05867749943579328
Singapore,2020-07-02 04:33:46,1.2833,103.8333,44122,26,39011,5085,Singapore,754.1780028965823,0.05892751915144372
Singapore,2020-07-01 04:33:52,1.2833,103.8333,43907,26,38500,5381,Singapore,750.5030046956222,0.05921607033047122
Singapore,2020-06-30 04:33:48,1.2833,103.8333,43661,26,37985,5650,Singapore,746.298123033128,0.05954971256
Singapore,2020-06-29 04:33:44,1.2833,103.8333,43459,26,37508,5925,Singapore,742.8453340257144,0.05982650314089141
Singapore,2020-06-28 04:34:04,1.2833,103.8333,43246,26,37163,6057,Singapore,739.2045218545305,0.06012116727558618
Singapore,2020-06-27 04:33:35,1.2833,103.8333,42955,26,36825,6104,Singapore,734.2304545220682,0.06052846001629612
Singapore,2020-06-26 04:33:43,1.2833,103.8333,42736,26,36604,6106,Singapore,730.4870842615553,0.0608386372145264
Singapore,2020-06-25 05:26:54,1.2833,103.8333,42623,26,36299,6298,Singapore,728.5555735791902,0.060999929615465825
Singapore,2020-06-24 04:33:28,1.2833,103.8333,42432,26,35995,6411,Singapore,725.2908077355464,0.061274509803921566
Singapore,2020-06-23 04:33:22,1.2833,103.8333,42313,26,35590,6697,Singapore,723.2567389638522,0.06144683666958145
Singapore,2020-06-22 04:33:20,1.2833,103.8333,42095,26,34942,7127,Singapore,719.5304617182275,0.06176505523221285
Singapore,2020-06-21 04:33:19,1.2833,103.8333,41833,26,34224,7583,Singapore,715.0520918175225,0.06215188965649129
Singapore,2020-06-20 04:33:19,1.2833,103.8333,41615,26,33459,8130,Singapore,711.3258145718977,0.06247747206536105
Singapore,2020-06-19 04:33:17,1.2833,103.8333,41473,26,32712,8735,Singapore,708.8986064577753,0.06269138957876208
Singapore,2020-06-18 04:33:18,1.2833,103.8333,41216,26,31938,9252,Singapore,704.5057016315112,0.06308229813664597
Singapore,2020-06-17 04:33:21,1.2833,103.8333,40969,26,31163,9780,Singapore,700.2837269541291,0.06346261807708267
Singapore,2020-06-16 04:33:09,1.2833,103.8333,40818,26,30366,10426,Singapore,697.7026817060128,0.06369738840707531
Singapore,2020-06-15 03:33:14,1.2833,103.8333,40604,26,29589,10989,Singapore,694.0447765199408,0.06403310018717367
Singapore,2020-06-14 03:33:15,1.2833,103.8333,40197,26,28808,11363,Singapore,687.0879194604487,0.06468144388884743
Singapore,2020-06-13 03:33:14,1.2833,103.8333,39850,25,28040,11785,Singapore,681.1566432942478,0.06273525721455459
Singapore,2020-06-12 05:09:52,1.2833,103.8333,39387,25,27286,12076,Singapore,673.2425774010173,0.06347271942519106
Singapore,2020-06-11 03:33:41,1.2833,103.8333,38965,25,26532,12408,Singapore,666.0293251182025,0.06416014371872193
Singapore,2020-06-10 04:07:00,1.2833,103.8333,38514,25,25877,12612,Singapore,658.3203754036302,0.06491146076751311
Singapore,2020-06-09 03:33:03,1.2833,103.8333,38296,25,25368,12903,Singapore,654.5940981580054,0.06528096929183204
Singapore,2020-06-08 03:33:22,1.2833,103.8333,37910,25,24886,12999,Singapore,647.9961944111653,0.06594566077552097
Singapore,2020-06-07 03:53:30,1.2833,103.8333,37527,25,24559,12943,Singapore,641.4495697089897,0.06661870120180137
Singapore,2020-06-06 02:33:00,1.2833,103.8333,37183,24,24209,12950,Singapore,635.5695725874534,0.06454562568915903
Singapore,2020-06-05 02:33:06,1.2833,103.8333,36922,24,23904,12994,Singapore,631.1082957016366,0.06500189588863009
Singapore,2020-06-04 02:33:14,1.2833,103.8333,36405,24,23582,12799,Singapore,622.271207004444,0.06592501030078286
Singapore,2020-06-03 02:33:13,1.2833,103.8333,35836,24,23175,12637,Singapore,612.5452815330657,0.06697176024109834
Singapore,2020-06-02 02:33:08,1.2833,103.8333,35292,24,22466,12802,Singapore,603.246681433892,0.06800408024481469
Singapore,2020-06-01 02:32:46,1.2833,103.8333,34884,23,21699,13162,Singapore,596.2727313595118,0.06593280587088636
Singapore,2020-05-31 02:32:45,1.2833,103.8333,34366,23,20727,13616,Singapore,587.418549647431,0.06692661351335623
Singapore,2020-05-30 02:32:48,1.2833,103.8333,33860,23,19631,14206,Singapore,578.7694841140084,0.06792675723567632
Singapore,2020-05-29 02:32:50,1.2833,103.8333,33249,23,18294,14932,Singapore
Singapore,2020-05-28 02:32:31,1.2833,103.8333,32876,23,17276,15577,Singapore
Singapore,2020-05-27 02:32:31,1.2833,103.8333,32343,23,16444,15876,Singapore
Singapore,2020-05-26 02:32:35,1.2833,103.8333,31960,23,15738,16199,Singapore
Singapore,2020-05-25 02:32:44,1.2833,103.8333,31616,23,14876,16717,Singapore
Singapore,2020-05-24 02:32:43,1.2833,103.8333,31068,23,13882,17163,Singapore
Singapore,2020-05-23 02:32:42,1.2833,103.8333,30426,23,12995,17408,Singapore
Singapore,2020-05-22 02:36:51,1.2833,103.8333,29812,23,12117,17672,Singapore
Singapore,2020-05-21 02:32:48,1.2833,103.8333,29364,22,11207,18135,Singapore
Singapore,2020-05-20 02:32:19,1.2833,103.8333,28794,22,10365,18407,Singapore
Singapore,2020-05-19 02:32:18,1.2833,103.8333,28343,22,9835,18486,Singapore
Singapore,2020-05-18 02:32:21,1.2833,103.8333,28038,22,9340,18676,Singapore
Singapore,2020-05-17 02:32:32,1.2833,103.8333,27356,22,8342,18992,Singapore
Singapore,2020-05-16 02:32:19,1.2833,103.8333,26891,21,7248,19622,Singapore
Singapore,2020-05-15 02:33:02,1.2833,103.8333,26098,21,5973,20104,Singapore
Singapore,2020-05-14 03:32:28,1.2833,103.8333,25346,21,4809,20516,Singapore
Singapore,2020-05-13 03:32:26,1.2833,103.8333,24671,21,3851,20799,Singapore
Singapore,2020-05-12 03:32:27,1.2833,103.8333,23822,21,3225,20576,Singapore
Singapore,2020-05-11 02:32:30,1.2833,103.8333,23336,20,2721,20595,Singapore
Singapore,2020-05-10 02:32:30,1.2833,103.8333,22460,20,2296,20144,Singapore
Singapore,2020-05-09 02:32:35,1.2833,103.8333,21707,20,2040,19647,Singapore
Singapore,2020-05-08 02:32:32,1.2833,103.8333,20939,20,1712,19207,Singapore
Singapore,2020-05-07 02:32:28,1.2833,103.8333,20198,20,1634,18544,Singapore
Singapore,2020-05-06 02:32:31,1.2833,103.8333,19410,18,1519,17873,Singapore
Singapore,2020-05-05 02:32:34,1.2833,103.8333,18778,18,1457,17303,Singapore
Singapore,2020-05-04 02:32:28,1.2833,103.8333,18205,18,1408,16779,Singapore
Singapore,2020-05-03 02:32:28,1.2833,103.8333,17548,17,1347,16184,Singapore
Singapore,2020-05-02 02:32:27,1.2833,103.8333,17101,16,1268,15817,Singapore
Singapore,2020-05-01 02:32:28,1.2833,103.8333,16169,15,1244,14910,Singapore
Singapore,2020-04-30 02:32:27,1.2833,103.8333,15641,14,1188,14439,Singapore
Singapore,2020-04-29 02:32:29,1.2833,103.8333,14951,14,1128,13809,Singapore
Singapore,2020-04-28 02:30:32,1.2833,103.8333,14423,14,1095,13314,Singapore
Singapore,2020-04-27 02:30:33,1.2833,103.8333,13624,12,1060,12552,Singapore
Singapore,2020-04-26 02:30:31,1.2833,103.8333,12693,12,1002,11679,Singapore
Singapore,2020-04-25 06:30:33,1.2833,103.8333,12075,12,956,11107,Singapore
Singapore,2020-04-24 03:30:31,1.2833,103.8333,11178,12,924,10242,Singapore
Singapore,2020-04-22 23:30:32,1.2833,103.8333,10141,12,896,9233,Singapore
Singapore,2020-04-21 23:30:30,1.2833,103.8333,9125,11,839,8275,Singapore
Singapore,2020-04-20 23:36:27,1.2833,103.8333,8014,11,801,7202,Singapore
Singapore,2020-04-19 23:40:41,1.2833,103.8333,6588,11,768,5809,Singapore
Singapore,2020-04-18 22:32:28,1.2833,103.8333,5992,11,740,5241,Singapore
Singapore,2020-04-17 23:30:32,1.2833,103.8333,5050,11,708,4331,Singapore
Singapore,2020-04-16 23:30:31,1.2833,103.8333,4427,10,683,3734,Singapore
Singapore,2020-04-15 22:56:32,1.2833,103.8333,3699,10,652,3037,Singapore
Singapore,2020-04-14 23:33:12,1.2833,103.8333,3252,10,611,2631,Singapore
Singapore,2020-04-13 23:07:34,1.2833,103.8333,2918,9,586,2323,Singapore
Singapore,2020-04-12 23:17:00,1.2833,103.8333,2532,8,560,1964,Singapore
Singapore,2020-04-11 22:45:13,1.2833,103.8333,2299,8,528,1763,Singapore
Singapore,2020-04-10 22:53:48,1.2833,103.8333,2108,7,492,1609,Singapore
Singapore,2020-04-09 23:02:19,1.2833,103.8333,1910,6,460,1444,Singapore
Singapore,2020-04-08 22:51:39,1.2833,103.8333,1623,6,406,1211,Singapore
Singapore,2020-04-07 23:04:29,1.2833,103.8333,1481,6,377,1098,Singapore
Singapore,2020-04-05 23:06:26,1.2833,103.8333,1309,6,320,983,Singapore
Singapore,2020-04-03 22:46:20,1.2833,103.8333,1114,5,282,827,Singapore
Singapore,2020-04-01 21:58:34,1.2833,103.8333,1000,3,245,752,Singapore
Singapore,2020-03-31 23:43:43,1.2833,103.8333,926,3,240,683,Singapore
Singapore,2020-03-27 23:23:03,1.2833,103.8333,732,2,183,547,Singapore
Singapore,2020-03-26 23:48:18,1.2833,103.8333,683,2,172,509,Singapore
Singapore,2020-03-25 23:33:04,1.2833,103.8333,631,2,160,469,Singapore
Singapore,2020-03-24 23:37:15,1.2833,103.8333,558,2,156,400,Singapore
Singapore,2020-03-23 23:19:21,1.2833,103.8333,509,2,152,355,Singapore
Singapore,2020-03-21T13:13:30,432,2,140,1.3521,103.8198
Singapore,2020-03-20T15:43:24,385,0,124,1.3521,103.8198
Singapore,2020-03-19T16:13:36,345,0,114,1.3521,103.8198
Singapore,2020-03-18T13:33:12,313,0,114,1.3521,103.8198
Singapore,2020-03-17T15:33:06,266,0,114,1.3521,103.8198
Singapore,2020-03-16T14:38:45,243,0,109,1.3521,103.8198
Singapore,2020-03-15T18:20:18,226,0,105,1.3521,103.8198
Singapore,2020-03-14T16:14:30,212,0,105,1.3521,103.8198
Singapore,2020-03-11T20:00:00,200,0,97,1.3521,103.8198
Singapore,2020-03-11T13:53:24,178,0,96,1.2833,103.8333
Singapore,2020-03-11T13:53:24,178,0,96,1.2833,103.8333
Singapore,2020-03-10T05:13:07,160,0,78,1.2833,103.8333
Singapore,2020-03-08T13:33:13,150,0,78,1.2833,103.8333
Singapore,2020-03-08T13:33:13,150,0,78,1.2833,103.8333
Singapore,2020-03-07T17:53:03,138,0,78,1.2833,103.8333
Singapore,2020-03-06T13:03:12,130,0,78,1.2833,103.8333
Singapore,2020-03-05T13:43:04,117,0,78,1.2833,103.8333
Singapore,2020-03-03T15:23:03,110,0,78,1.2833,103.8333
Singapore,2020-03-03T15:23:03,110,0,78,1.2833,103.8333
Singapore,2020-03-02T20:33:02,108,0,78,1.2833,103.8333
Singapore,2020-03-01T23:23:02,106,0,72,1.2833,103.8333
Singapore,2020-02-29T14:33:03,102,0,72
Singapore,2020-02-26T19:33:02,93,0,62
Singapore,2020-02-26T19:33:02,93,0,62
Singapore,2020-02-26T19:33:02,93,0,62
Singapore,2020-02-25T18:55:32,91,0,53
Singapore,2020-02-23T15:13:15,89,0,51
Singapore,2020-02-23T15:13:15,89,0,51
Singapore,2020-02-21T03:43:02,85,0,37
Singapore,2020-02-21T03:43:02,85,0,37
Singapore,2020-02-19T22:13:08,84,0,34
Singapore,2020-02-19T22:13:08,84,0,34
Singapore,2020-02-18T16:53:03,81,0,29
Singapore,2020-02-17T14:33:04,77,0,24
Singapore,2020-02-16T16:23:06,75,0,18
Singapore,2020-02-15T23:53:02,72,0,18
Singapore,2020-02-14T12:43:02,67,0,17
Singapore,2020-02-13T14:33:02,58,0,15
Singapore,2020-02-12T19:53:02,50,0,15
Singapore,2020-02-11T16:43:06,47,0,9
Singapore,2020-02-10T19:03:02,45,0,2
Singapore,2020-02-09T02:43:02,40,0,2
Singapore,2020-02-08T12:53:01,33,0,2
Singapore,2020-02-07T03:03:03,30,0,0
Singapore,2020-02-05T16:33:03,28,0,0
Singapore,2020-02-05T16:33:03,28,0,0
Singapore,2020-02-04T15:33:03,24,0,0
Singapore,2020-02-02T01:03:32,18,0,0
Singapore,2020-02-02T01:03:32,18,0,0
```

Be aware that your date format changes within your file. But here it is not critical.

```
Singapore,2020-08-22 04:27:49,1.2833,103.8333,56216,27,53651,2538,Singapore,960.9009249543145,0.048029030880888
...
Singapore,2020-02-05T16:33:03,28,0,0
```

**Code:**

```
### plot daily change 
reset session

FILE = "Singapore.csv"
set datafile separator comma

set format x "%m/%d" timedate
x1=NaN
y1=NaN
plot FILE u (x0=x1,x1=timecolumn(2,"%Y-%m-%d")):(y0=y1,y1=$5,(y1-y0)/(x1-x0)*3600*24) \
    w lp pt 7 title "Daily change"
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: I don't quite understand how you reference the second column for Y, because in my data I have a few columns I need to work upon: https://github.com/kaihendry/covid19-sg/blob/master/gnuplot.ipynb

Comment: `$2` is the column of your data. If your data is in the 7th column, write `$7` or `column(7)` instead.

Comment: Thanks, though why am I getting negative values here? https://github.com/kaihendry/covid19-sg/blob/master/gnuplot.ipynb

Comment: because your data is different compared to your question. a) it is reverse, i.e. newest date at the beginning, b) it's not on a stricly daily basis and c) the date/time format is actually `"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"`(but maybe the latter is not so important).

Comment: Thanks, I re-ordered the data, but now the X axis is messed up. https://github.com/kaihendry/covid19-sg/blob/master/gnuplot.ipynb

Comment: well, you could have let your data as is, just replace `y1-y0` with `y0-y1`. Your x-axis is messed up because you set a tic every day `set xtics 3600*24` over 7 months this will be around 200 tics labels. There is simply not enough space. So just skip this line and gnuplot will do auto xlabels. Just to mention, your data is apparently not regular for every day, so the numbers you are plotting are not all a daily increase, but some of them an increase for two or more days. I guess I should modify the answer to cover the general case.

Comment: Thank you @theozh!! https://github.com/kaihendry/covid19-sg/blob/master/gnuplot.ipynb